# Json Muestra solo el último dato

Tags: android, json, parser

estoy desarrollando una app tipo catálogo de lugares, resulta que estoy obteniendo los datos de un Json y todo bien obtengo latitud, longitud y los demás datos pero tengo un problema con la imagen, ya que solo me muestra el último dato que tengo el json, todo lo demás lo muestra correctamente en el orden que debe ir pero para la imagen muestra el mismo url en todos los marcadores y ese url es el último del json, aquí el fragmento del código en el que supongo debe estar el error.

```
    private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {



        private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://espinosaits.com.mx/pruebaconexion/mapa.json";
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        // Invoked by execute() method of this object

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(tarque.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Cargando, Espera un momento");
            dialog.setTitle("Conectando al servidor");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // Connect to the web service
                URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
                int read;
                char[] buff = new char[4096];
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    json.append(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
                //throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); //uncaught
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

            return json.toString();
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json ) {
            dialog.cancel();

            try {
                // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    image = jsonObj.getString("image");

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1));





                    //move CameraPosition on first result
                    if (i == 0) {
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(latLng).zoom(10).build();

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                    }



                    // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                            .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                            .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
                            .position(latLng));


            }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }

        }
    }





    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(16.8581412, -99.8929664);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(3));
        //doStuff();
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

//AQUÏ VAN LOS MARCADORES
        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(    16.8535028,-99.906489   )).title("NOMBRE:   TAQUERÍA EL PUENTE\nCOLONIA:    HORNOS\nVIALIDAD:   FRACC. HORNOS\nTEL: ").snippet("    NO TIENE    ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));


        //Aquí TERMINAN los marcadores

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Información Detallada",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // num1(marker.getSnippet());

        String Abc;
        Abc = marker.getTitle();



        Intent i = new Intent(this, detalle.class);
        i.putExtra("firstName", Abc);
        i.putExtra("lastName",marker.getSnippet());
        i.putExtra("img",image);
        startActivity(i);


    }
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de la estructura json que describes para dar un diagnostico acertado.

Comment: AH si claro, [
    {"name":"   TAQUERÍA EL PUENTE\nCOLONIA: HORNOS\nVIALIDAD: FRACC. HORNOS\nTEL: ","latlng":[16.8535028,-99.906489],"telefono":5554545, "image": "http://foodandtravel.mx/home/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tacos.jpg"},]

Comment: el error consiste en que en efecto puedo leer el url del json y almacenarlo en la variable, pero al momento de que muestro en el ImageView dicho url me doy cuenta que todos son la misma imagen, es como si no leyera cada uno de los enlaces correspondientes a cada restaurante.

Comment: En el código no se ve la parte donde asignas la imagen al `imageView`. También, creo que deberías revisar si en efecto tu JSON tiene imágenes diferentes en cada caso.

Comment: si, en el json tengo url de imágenes diferentes y respecto al asignado de la imagen es esta. '  String uriPath = tv3.getText().toString();
        
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
     


        Glide.with(this)
                .load(uriPath)
                .into(im);'

Comment: @XavierEspinosa que te parece si agregas el código completo, incluido donde agregas la imagen. Lo comento porque puede estar dentro del loop el asignar la imagen o afuera que es donde se agregaria solo la última imagen.

Comment: listo @Jorgesys alli muestro desde la conexión para el Json y todo lo demás, he probado de mil maneras pero no logro captar porqué todos los datos los lee de uno en uno pero de la imagen solo muestra la última

Comment: Estuve checando y el problema no es la asignación de la imagen ya que si lo hace, el problema es que el valor de la url lo asigno a una variable pero esa variable solo esta almacenando el último dato del Json, la idea es que dependiendo a cada restaurante lea su imagen respectiva, pero no lo hace para todos solo muestra ese último url que hay en mi Json

Answer (score 3):

El problema esta en la forma como estas almacenando los markers y el enfoque general del código.

Para solucionar el problema Primero crea un objeto MarkerInfo con la informacion q debera tener cada Marker.

```
 private class MarkerInfo {
    public LatLng latLng;
    public String imageURL;
}
```

Luego crea una variable en tu actividad/fragment para almacenar la lista de marcadores.

```
 public ArrayList<MarkerInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

En el onPostexecute crea un nuevo objeto por marcador y agregalo a la lista.

```
image = jsonObj.getString("image");
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1));

MarkerInfo markerTemp = new MarkerInfo();
markerTemp.latLng = latLng;
markerTemp.imageURL = image;

list.add(markerTemp);
```

En el metodo OnMapReady inicializas cada marker con los objetos ya creados

```
for (MarkerInfo markerInfo : list) {
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerInfo.latLng));
}
```

Finalmente en el metodo OnInfo..

```
 for (MarkerInfo markerInfo : list) {
         if(marker.getTitle().contentEquals(markerInfo.title))
             // encuentro mi marker por titulo o por el campo que quieras filtarlo
         {
             Intent i = new Intent();
             i.putExtra("image",markerInfo.image);
             ...

             break;
         }
     }
```

Aqui podrias agregarle titulo , icono , imagen y todas las propiedades que necesites. Recordar que si vas a agregar mas propiedades debes agregarlas al objeto MarkerInfo y parsearla en el onPostExecute.

Con esto seguro se arreglaran tus problemas y tendras un codigo mas limpios y con menos bugs. Saludos.

Comment: vale voy a intentarlo muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que cuando realizas el parsing de los elementos en el Json, siempre estas sobreescribiendo el valor de `image`, que es usado para almacenar la url de imagen.

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    image = jsonObj.getString("image");
                    ...
```

una opción para solucionar esto es almacenar la url de la imagen en el tag del Marker:

```
marker.setTag(image);
```

y posteriormente obtenerla del tag para enviarla en el intent.

```
...
... 
     String titulo = marker.getTitle();
     String imagenUrl = marker.getTag(); //* obtiene url almacenado.

        Intent i = new Intent(this, detalle.class);
        i.putExtra("firstName", Abc);
        i.putExtra("lastName",marker.getSnippet());
        i.putExtra("img",imagenUrl);
        startActivity(i);
...
...
```

Comment: entiendo, de hecho había probado algo similar pero me enviaba un error al momento de ejecutar ya que al utilizar lo que colocaste como imagenUrl = marker.getTag(); me lo marcaba que tenia que utilizar el StringVauleOf y al usarlo se crasheaba jeje, y pues ya me puse a probar con otras vías, pero voy a intentar nuevamente con esta opción que me dices a ver que tal, muchas gracias :D

Comment: mmmmm me sucede lo mismo, en esta sección " String imagenUrl = marker.getTag();" me aparece el mensaje que se requiere java.lang.string y que solo encuentra java.lang.object pero si utilizo el StringValueOf  se elimina el error pero al ejecutar la app mi teléfono se crashea al entrar para ver los resultados